# How to refresh result completely by different actionbuttons in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app works well but there is a small problem that puzzled me.

There are three actionbuttons and all of them can create similar pictures and tables at the same time.

In my view, I hope each actionbutton can refresh the result generated by last button.
I modified my code but it doesn't work. And one or two empty area always appear.

**So my question is** what I can do to remove the empty areas. I hope each graph and each table could appear together without any space or distance just like the result that the first button generated.

###### The space like this:

[image]
[image]

###### Here is my code:

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(psych)              ## corr.test
library(DT)
library(pheatmap)
########

data<-structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
                              "C", "D"), `0610005C13Rik` = c(0.42, 0.28, 0.16, 0.14, 0.23, 
                                                             0.12, 0, 0.06, 0.09, 0.27), `0610006L08Rik` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                             0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `0610007P14Rik` = c(12.81, 11.44, 13.94, 14.26, 
                                                                                                                                                 14.95, 14.55, 6.61, 8.52, 7.68, 5.13), `0610009B22Rik` = c(7.53, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            6.55, 7.32, 7.12, 6.33, 7.12, 5.87, 3.57, 3.95, 3.49), `0610009E02Rik` = c(0.19, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.25, 0.23, 0.18, 0.28, 0.3, 0.26, 0.14, 0.11, 0.11), `0610009L18Rik` = c(1.32, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 1.61, 1.26, 0.78, 1.12, 0.95, 3.45, 1.36, 0.94, 1.31), `0610009O20Rik` = c(18.73, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            17.38, 18.56, 21.46, 22.64, 21.24, 20.85, 21.85, 17.9, 23.44), 
                     `0610010B08Rik` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `0610010F05Rik` = c(5.14, 
                                                                                            4.49, 4.68, 4.63, 4.5, 4.15, 1.74, 2.3, 2.03, 2.28), `0610010K14Rik` = c(34.97, 
                                                                                                                                                                     28.72, 32.6, 29.98, 29.93, 30.05, 38.07, 29.76, 28.63, 27.74
                                                                                            )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
data
######


ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel("666",
#      width = 9,
                  tabPanel("123",
                           hr(),
                           typeaheadInput(
                             "select", 
                             "Select", 
                             choices = NULL,
                             minLength = 1,
                             value = "0610005C13Rik"
                           ),
                           #####
                           actionButton(inputId = "plot_1", label = "123",width=80,class="btn btn-success"),
                           actionButton(inputId = "plot_2", label = "456",width=80,class="btn btn-light"),
                           actionButton(inputId = "plot_3", label = "789",width=80,class="btn btn-danger"),
                           hr(),
                           uiOutput("all"),
                           dataTableOutput('myTable1'),
                           dataTableOutput('myTable2'),
                           dataTableOutput('myTable3')
                           #####
                  )
      ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateTypeaheadInput(session, "select", choices = colnames(data[,-1]))
  observeEvent(list(input$plot_1,input$plot_2,input$plot_3), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "666",
                      selected = "123"
    )
  })

  #################
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL
  )
  
  ######
  output$all <- renderUI({                     
    global$out
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_1,{
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot_1")
    myData_2(NULL)
    myData_3(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_2, {
    
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot_2")
    myData_1(NULL)
    myData_3(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_3, {
    global$outtt <- plotOutput("myPlot_3")
    myData_1(NULL)
    myData_2(NULL)
  })
 
  #########################################
  ##
  myPlot_1 = reactiveVal()
  myPlot_2 = reactiveVal()
  myPlot_3 = reactiveVal()
  #
  myData_1 = reactiveVal()
  myData_2 = reactiveVal()
  myData_3 = reactiveVal()


  ####################################  1
  observeEvent(input$plot_1, {
    validate(need(sum(unique(colnames(data[,-1])) %in% input$select)>0, "The gene is not found."))
    data_cor<-data[,-1]
    tm <- corr.test(data_cor[,input$select,drop=FALSE],
                    y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                    alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
    res <-setNames(as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, tm[c("r", "p")]))), c("Correlation", "P_value"))
    res<-res[-which(rownames(res)== input$select),]
    res<-data.frame(Gene=rownames(res),res)
    res<-res[order(res$Correlation,decreasing = T),]
    rownames(res)<-NULL
    res<-na.omit(res)
    res
    ##############
    data_correlation=t(data[, -1])
    data_subset=data_correlation[c(input$select, as.vector(head(res$Gene, 9))), ]
    myPlot_1(
      
      if(nrow(data_subset)>1){
        pheatmap(log2(data_subset+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =13,
#                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_subset), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, 
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      }
    )
    myData_1(res)
  })        
  ######################################## 2
  observeEvent(input$plot_2, {
    validate(need(sum(unique(colnames(data[,-1])) %in% input$select)>0, "The gene is not found."))
    data_cor<-data[,-1]
    tm <- corr.test(data_cor[,input$select,drop=FALSE],
                    y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                    alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
    res <-setNames(as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, tm[c("r", "p")]))), c("Correlation", "P_value"))
    res<-res[-which(rownames(res)== input$select),]
    res<-data.frame(Gene=rownames(res),res)
    res<-res[order(res$Correlation,decreasing = T),]
    rownames(res)<-NULL
    res<-na.omit(res)
    res
    ##############
    data_correlation=t(data[, -1])
    data_subset=data_correlation[c(input$select, as.vector(head(res$Gene, 9))), ]
    myPlot_2(
      
      if(nrow(data_subset)>1){
        pheatmap(log2(data_subset+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =13,
                 #                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_subset), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, 
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      }
    )
    myData_2(res)
  })     
  ########################################  3
  observeEvent(input$plot_3, {
    validate(need(sum(unique(colnames(data[,-1])) %in% input$select)>0, "The gene is not found."))
    data_cor<-data[,-1]
    tm <- corr.test(data_cor[,input$select,drop=FALSE],
                    y = data_cor, use = "pairwise", "spearman", adjust="none", 
                    alpha=0.05, ci=F, minlength=5)
    res <-setNames(as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, tm[c("r", "p")]))), c("Correlation", "P_value"))
    res<-res[-which(rownames(res)== input$select),]
    res<-data.frame(Gene=rownames(res),res)
    res<-res[order(res$Correlation,decreasing = T),]
    rownames(res)<-NULL
    res<-na.omit(res)
    res
    ##############
    data_correlation=t(data[, -1])
    data_subset=data_correlation[c(input$select, as.vector(head(res$Gene, 9))), ]
    myPlot_3(
      
      if(nrow(data_subset)>1){
        pheatmap(log2(data_subset+1), show_colnames = F,fontsize_row =13,
                 #                 labels_row = as.expression(lapply(rownames(data_subset), function(a) bquote(italic(.(a))))),
                 cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, 
                 fontsize = 11,
                 cellwidth=4
        )
      }
    )
    myData_3(res)
  })     
  ###################################  1
  output$myPlot_1 = renderPlot({
    req(myPlot_1())
    myPlot_1()
  })
  
  output$myTable1 = renderDataTable({
    req(myData_1())

    myData_1()
    
  })
  #################################  2
  output$myPlot_2 = renderPlot({

    req(myPlot_2())
    myPlot_2()
  })
  
  output$myTable2 = renderDataTable({

    req(myData_2())
    
    myData_2()
    
  })
  #################################  3
  output$myPlot_3 = renderPlot({

    req(myPlot_3())
    myPlot_3()
  })
  
  output$myTable3 = renderDataTable({

    req(myData_3())
    
    myData_3()
    
  })
  
}

###################

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

who can help me

Comment: @YBS Sir I need your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to plot, you could to output the tables in a `renderUI`.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel("666",
            #      width = 9,
            tabPanel("123",
                     hr(),
                     selectInput(
                       "select", 
                       "Select", 
                       choices = NULL#,
                       # minLength = 1,
                       # value = "0610005C13Rik"
                     ),
                     #####
                     actionButton(inputId = "plot_1", label = "123",width=80,class="btn btn-success"),
                     actionButton(inputId = "plot_2", label = "456",width=80,class="btn btn-light"),
                     actionButton(inputId = "plot_3", label = "789",width=80,class="btn btn-danger"),
                     hr(),
                     uiOutput("all"),
                     uiOutput("mydata")
                     # dataTableOutput('myTable1'),
                     # dataTableOutput('myTable2'),
                     # dataTableOutput('myTable3')
                     #####
            )
  ))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateSelectInput(session, "select", choices = colnames(data[,-1]))
  observeEvent(list(input$plot_1,input$plot_2,input$plot_3), {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "666",
                      selected = "123"
    )
  })
  
  #################
  global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL, data = NULL
  )
  
  ######
  output$all <- renderUI({                     
    global$out
  })
  output$mydata <- renderUI({                     
    global$data
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_1,{
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot_1")
    global$data <- DTOutput("myTable1")
    # myData_2(NULL)
    # myData_3(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_2, {
    
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot_2")
    global$data <- DTOutput("myTable2")
    # myData_1(NULL)
    # myData_3(NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$plot_3, {
    global$out <- plotOutput("myPlot_3")
    global$data <- DTOutput("myTable3")
    # myData_1(NULL)
    # myData_2(NULL)
  })
```

Comment: Sorry sir, if I  use three different data, like data1, data2 and data3 for the three pictures and tables, respectively, how should I modify the code above ? I just have a try, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If you use three different outputs, such as, `DTOutput("data1")` in the `ui`, you will have a blank space for the null data - as shown in your code.

Comment: Yes, I know. But there are three different data(data,data1 and data2) . Should I modify my code like this: global <- reactiveValues(out = NULL, data = NULL, data1=NULL,data2=NULL)  ?

Comment: For the above MRE, my code works for me.  Is that not the case for you? To display 3 different data tables, you can go with your suggestion.